# Loading data into mysql LOAD DATA INFILE difficulty

Tags: mysql

I am executing the following query to load the data into MySQL.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/ramjiseetharaman/Desktop/UTA/CSE\ 5330\ -\ Database\ Systems/Projects/Project\ 1/DEPARTMENT.txt'
INTO TABLE DEPARTMENT
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY "'"
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n";
```

And I am getting the following warnings,

```
| Level   | Code | Message                                                               |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: ' '333445555'' for column 'Mgr_ssn' at row 1 |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: ' '987654321'' for column 'Mgr_ssn' at row 2 |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: ' '888665555'' for column 'Mgr_ssn' at row 3 |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: ' '111111100'' for column 'Mgr_ssn' at row 4 |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: ' '444444400'' for column 'Mgr_ssn' at row 5 |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: ' '555555500'' for column 'Mgr_ssn' at row 6 |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: ' '112244668'' for column 'Mgr_ssn' at row 7 |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: ' '110110110'' for column 'Mgr_ssn' at row 8 |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: ' '913323708'' for column 'Mgr_ssn' at row 9 |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to load the following data:

```
'Research', 5, '333445555', '22-MAY-1978'
'Administration', 4, '987654321', '01-JAN-1985'
'Headquarters', 1, '888665555', '19-JUN-1971'
'Software', 6, '111111100', '15-MAY-1999'
'Hardware', 7, '444444400', '15-MAY-1998'
'Sales', 8, '555555500', '01-JAN-1997'
'HR', 9, '112244668', '01-FEB-1989'
'Networking', 3, '110110110', '15-MAY-2009'
'QA', 11, '913323708', '2-FEB-2010'
```

What am I missing in the query? Why is that the Manager_Ssn doesn't load? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well the error message is pretty clear, at least to me.  The third column of your data is text but apparently the `DEPARTMENT` table is expecting an int/numeric data type there.  You should post your table definition.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - The third column is a BIGINT Tim. The weird part is that, I was able to insert with the same query, the data similar with another table and its working good!

Comment: DESC DEPARTMENT;
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| Dnumber        | tinyint(4)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Mgr_ssn        | bigint(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
This is the schema and if you can see the Dnumber is TINYINT

Comment: And the data for the Dnumber gets inserted. This is the result of the query
 Dname            | Dnumber | Mgr_ssn | Mgr_start_date |
| 'Headquarters'   |       1 |       0 | '19-JUN-1971'  |
 |'Networking'     |       3 |       0 | '15-MAY-2009'
 |'Administration' |       4 |       0 | '01-JAN-1985'
 |'Research'       |       5 |       0 | '22-MAY-1978'
 |'Software'       |       6 |       0 | '15-MAY-1999'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

- `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','` by `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ', '`.
- Format the `Mgr_start_date` column.

Try:

File: `/path/to/file/DEPARTMENT.txt`:

```bsh
'Research', 5, '333445555', '22-MAY-1978'
'Administration', 4, '987654321', '01-JAN-1985'
'Headquarters', 1, '888665555', '19-JUN-1971'
'Software', 6, '111111100', '15-MAY-1999'
'Hardware', 7, '444444400', '15-MAY-1998'
'Sales', 8, '555555500', '01-JAN-1997'
'HR', 9, '112244668', '01-FEB-1989'
'Networking', 3, '110110110', '15-MAY-2009'
'QA', 11, '913323708', '2-FEB-2010'
```

MySQL Command-Line:

```sql
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `DEPARTMENT`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `DEPARTMENT` (
    ->   `Dname` VARCHAR(255),
    ->   `Dnumber` TINYINT(4),
    ->   `Mgr_ssn` BIGINT(20),
    ->   `Mgr_start_date` DATE
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/file/DEPARTMENT.txt'
    ->   INTO TABLE DEPARTMENT
    ->   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ', '
    ->   ENCLOSED BY "'"
    ->   LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
    ->   (`Dname`, `Dnumber`, `Mgr_ssn`, @`Mgr_start_date`)
    ->   SET `Mgr_start_date` = STR_TO_DATE(@`Mgr_start_date`, '%d-%M-%Y');
Query OK, 9 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 9  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `Dname`,
    ->   `Dnumber`,
    ->   `Mgr_ssn`,
    ->   `Mgr_start_date`
    -> FROM
    ->   `DEPARTMENT`;
+----------------+---------+-----------+----------------+
| Dname          | Dnumber | Mgr_ssn   | Mgr_start_date |
+----------------+---------+-----------+----------------+
| Research       |       5 | 333445555 | 1978-05-22     |
| Administration |       4 | 987654321 | 1985-01-01     |
| Headquarters   |       1 | 888665555 | 1971-06-19     |
| Software       |       6 | 111111100 | 1999-05-15     |
| Hardware       |       7 | 444444400 | 1998-05-15     |
| Sales          |       8 | 555555500 | 1997-01-01     |
| HR             |       9 | 112244668 | 1989-02-01     |
| Networking     |       3 | 110110110 | 2009-05-15     |
| QA             |      11 | 913323708 | 2010-02-02     |
+----------------+---------+-----------+----------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```